# Ubuntu supports Oracle Berkely DB........?

Tags: 12.04

I want to ask about how oracle berkely db works with ubuntu servers with a crm application(using php), it is a open source oracle product or not...? can we setup this in our production servers.

Thank You.

A.chandrasekhar

Comment: In theory it should work. http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libdb5.1++ and / or complie if you prefer http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/berkeleydb/installation/installing_berkeleydb_on_ubuntu_linux.php

Answer (score 1):

The [Oracle Berkeley DB is here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/overview/index.html). [This says the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_04/html/gsg/JAVA/index.html) is under the open source license. Aha! [The Open Source license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/downloads/oslicense-093458.html) also applies to the software too.

Storage limits:  *An individual DB database can store up to 256 terabytes of data. By using multiple databases, it is possible to use DB to store and manage petabytes of information. Within a single database, individual record keys or record data can be used to store up to 4 gigabytes of data.*

NOTE: This looks different than the Berkeley DB that comes with Perl, which has a limit of 1009 bytes for the length of data and key combined.